# Cannot import tensorflow in jupyter: Kernel Restarting

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter, conda, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to run the following code block in my jupyter locally:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
```

Unfortunately, this leads to the problem `The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.`
I found a lot of questions with the same problem, but no one could help me to solve my issue.
I tried to reinstall all the packages and the anaconda-navigator but it didn't change anything.
**Configuration:**
Mac M1 with 32GB Ram.
**UPDATE:**
I tried to run the code from a `.py`file and I got the following error `zsh: illegal hardware instruction python fileName.py`.

Comment: Did you install anaconda for silicon macs? Or using a Jupyter kernel in a simple Python instalation? And did you install the tensorflow-macos pip package?

Comment: yes I installed anaconda-navigator for MacOS. For tensorflow I installed the package in the first using `pip` and after as in other questions mentioned using ´conda`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could solve the problem, I hope it could help someone in the future.
So the first thing, the first shown in the first (in jupyter notebook) was unclear and it is just a standard saying that something went wrong, so as I mentioned in my update section, I tried to run the code from a `.py` file to see the original problem.
So installing anaconda and tensorflow package and then running jupyter will work without any problem for windows maybe but not for MacOSX, so to install it for Mac M1 it could be challenging somehow, I followed [this link](https://www.mrdbourke.com/setup-apple-m1-pro-and-m1-max-for-machine-learning-and-data-science/) and I could successfully install it and everything works fine now !

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue on Apple M1 Pro with 16Gb RAM.

Followed the answer provided by @Gothiquo and [this link](https://www.mrdbourke.com/setup-apple-m1-pro-and-m1-max-for-machine-learning-and-data-science/).

Make a slight modification and workable to run tensorflow on jupyter-lab on CPU-only

Create a new conda environment

```
conda create --prefix ./env_tf python=3.8 
conda activate ./env_tf
```

Install the deps

```
conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps
```

Install tensorflow

```
python -m pip install tensorflow-macos
```

And I didn't install tensorflow-metal mentioned in the blog post. Although I cannot use GPU on my Mac without installing tensorflow-metal, it runs on CPU with a satisfactory speed (for myself). It will crush my jupyter-lab when running on GPU and lead to "kernel died".

After that install data science packages

```
conda install jupyter pandas numpy matplotlib scikit-learn
```

Finally call my jupyter-lab

```
jupyter-lab
```

Try to run the following code on a testing notebook, and if it works, it should work on other model structures.

```
import tensorflow as tf
inputs = tf.keras.Inputs(shape = (10))
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(inputs)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = outputs)
```

Currently, it works only on python 3.8 on my mac.